# Problem with the use of the $lookup pipeline stage: performance issue and usage

Tags: mongodb

It's the first time I post here so I hope my request is redacted as it should, but I'm sorry in advance if it's not.

I'm very new to mongodb and I'm trying to perform a $lookup operation on a collection named "builds", which stores about 15.000 documents.
Here's the structure of a document stored in this collection:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bc4d54c4d92ca946f67a8f4"), 
    "branch" : "master", 
    "build_number" : 11018, 
    "change" : "390494", 
    "commit" : "241a12e27baf40aa874687d289a2b5cc02d3d143", 
    "directory_size" : 621485449, 
    "duration" : "2035435", 
    "fingerprints" : { 
        "commit" : "266e3227d2d68b309998f963bd46653b", 
        "legacyTreeish" : "e14967681cf356d67b2480704d3ed6bf", 
        "subtree" : "45fb7898dc1cf0c7ffda3e9e03797953", 
        "treeish" : "f190542db721000900d33e77090e3dd3" 
    }, 
    "job" : "MASTER_PROD/UPLANE/L2-PS/BUILD.bbp", 
    "patchset" : "2", 
    "pipeline" : "gate", 
    "project" : "MN/5G/NB/gnb", 
    "release" : "18A", 
    "result" : "SUCCESS", 
    "retries" : 0, 
    "reused" : 0, 
    "server" : "es-si-os-ohn-65-5g-ci-common-6d9", 
    "startTime" : "1531304202954", 
    "timestamp" : "1531304202953", 
    "uuid" : "f51420141dc94a03a58bbd28fa35f6c9", 
    "voting" : true 
}
```

EDIT: I'm trying to perform my request using the mongo shell.

I'm trying to perform a request to look for documents that:

1. Have the result key set to "SUCCESS" AND the pipeline key set to "check".
2. Are such as at least another one document exist with the same pipeline, job, change and patchset and a different result than "SUCCESS".

Here's my request:

```
db.builds.aggregate(
    [
        { $match:   { pipeline: "check", result: "SUCCESS" } },
        { $lookup:  { 
                from: "builds", 
                let: { change: "$change", patchset: "$patchset", result: "$result", job: "$job", pipeline: "$pipeline" }, 
                pipeline: [
                    { $match: { 
                        $expr: { 
                            $and: 
                                [
                                    { $eq: [ "$$change", "$change"]},
                                    { $eq: [ "$$patchset", "$patchset"]},
                                    { $eq: [ "$$pipeline", "check" ]},
                                    { $eq: [ "$$job", "$job" ]},
                                    { $ne: [ "$$result", "SUCCESS" ]}
                                ]         
                        }
                    }
                }    
                ],
                as: "unstables"
            } 
        },
        { $project: { unstables: 1} }
    ]
)
```

I have two problems with this request:

1. It takes several minutes when I use the last project operation, and only a few seconds when I don't. I do have 1 index for each of the following keys in my collection: change, patchset, job, pipeline and result. I guess I did something very wrong but I'm not able to identify what.
2. The "unstables" array which is filled by the $lookup pipeline stage is always empty. According to what I was told about the data in the collection, it shouldn't be the case. I guess my use of the $lookup operation is wrong but I don't know why.

I would be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction to fix this messy request ! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing a mistake with use of $$ in pipeline stage : $$ acts for 'base' collection, $ for 'joined' collection. As you filter with $match on pipeline and result,

```
{ $eq: [ "$$change", "$change"]},
{ $eq: [ "$$patchset", "$patchset"]},
{ $eq: [ "$$pipeline", "check" ]},      ===> always true
{ $eq: [ "$$job", "$job" ]},
{ $ne: [ "$$result", "SUCCESS" ]}       ===> always false
```

Here's the right syntax :

```
{ $eq: [ "$$change", "$change"]},
{ $eq: [ "$$patchset", "$patchset"]},
{ $eq: [ "$pipeline", "check" ]},    // or { $eq: [ "$pipeline", "$$pipeline" ]}
{ $eq: [ "$$job", "$job" ]},
{ $ne: [ "$result", "SUCCESS" ]}     // or { $ne: [ "$result", "$$result" ]}
```

But you can achieve the same without using $lookup stage, by translating your need : 
You need builds, with

- the same change, patchset, job
- where pipeline = "check"
- where there is at least one "SUCCESS" and one other value for result.

You can do this with the following :

```
db.builds.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      pipeline: "check",

    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        change: "$change",
        patchset: "$patchset",
        job: "$job",
        pipeline: "$pipeline"
      },
      builds: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      },
      resultset: {
        $addToSet: "$result"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            $gt: [
              {
                $size: "$resultset"
              },
              1
            ]
          },
          {
            $in: [
              "SUCCESS",
              "$resultset"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can test it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_XO33Wb8Owh). Hope it helps

Comment: Yes thank you so much it's exactly what I missed ! I was misled by the mongodb documentation page about the $lookup pipeline stage which is exactly the opposite of what you said, and you were right.
Moreover your second suggestion is far more efficient and logical ! Thank you very much for your help :)